# TensorFlow Serving crossed columns strange error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am receiving the following error when trying to send a prediction request to my saved model, running with TensorFlow Serving:

```
{
    "error": "Expected D2 of index to be 2 got 3 at position 0\n\t [[{{node linear/linear_model/linear_model/linear_model/int2Id_X_stringId/SparseCross}}]]"
}
```

The problem appears to come from trying to use crossed columns in a linear model...?

My model in service is a tf.estimator.LinearClassifier . My REST API request is a POST to 'model_directory/model:predict' with the following intput:

```
{ "signature_name": "predict",
    "instances": [{
         "intId" : [2],
        "int2Id": [847],
        "int3Id": [0],
        "int4Id":[3],
        "stringId" : ["STRING"]}]
}
```

Strangely, locally using the saved_model_cli with the following command to get a prediction works absolutely fine:

```
saved_model_cli run --dir Workspace/saves/1567433674 --tag_set serve --signature_def predict --input_exprs int4Id=[3];int1Id=[2];stringId=['STRING'];int3Id=[0];int2Id=[847]
```

The goal is to have a prediction output from my served model, an output similar to when I use saved_model_cli. Something like this:

```
Result for output key all_class_ids:
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]]
Result for output key all_classes:
[[b'0' b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4' b'5']]
Result for output key class_ids:
[[2]]
Result for output key classes:
[[b'2']]
Result for output key logits:
[[ 0.11128154 -0.44881764  0.31520572 -0.08318427 -0.3479367  -0.08883157]]
Result for output key probabilities:
[[0.19719791 0.11263006 0.2418051  0.16234797 0.12458517 0.16143374]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "instances" to "inputs" and have another try.