# TensorFlow Serving Error: 'StatelessIf has '_lower_using_switch_merge' attr set but it does not support lowering.'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

When attempting to serve a new model coded using TensorFlow 2.0 with TensorFlow serving, I get the following error from my Docker container logs:

```
2019-09-03 08:56:24.984824: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/model_modeFact/1567500955
2019-09-03 08:56:24.989902: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-09-03 08:56:25.002593: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:311] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail. Took 17772 microseconds.
2019-09-03 08:56:25.002658: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name: model_modeFact version: 1567500955} failed: Internal: Node {{node zero_fraction/total_zero/zero_count/else/_1/zero_fraction/cond}} of type StatelessIf has '_lower_using_switch_merge' attr set but it does not support lowering.
```

Using the saved_model_cli, the model works fine and can make predictions.
Initially I was getting this error: "[TensorFlow Serving crossed columns strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758785/tensorflow-serving-crossed-columns-strange-error)"

I found that this error might be fixed by swapping to tf-nightly-2.0-preview==2.0.0.dev20190819
But instead I am now I can't even get my model to be served.

The only changes I made to the code to compile my model in TF2 are:

```
# Added this line to force eager execution, necessary for tf.placeholders
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# For every usage of tf.estimator...
tf.compat.v1.estimator

# For every usage of tf.placeholder...
tf.compat.v1.placeholder
```

Like the previous problem, the goal is to have a prediction output from my served model, an output similar to when I use saved_model_cli. Something like this:

```
Result for output key all_class_ids:
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]]
Result for output key all_classes:
[[b'0' b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4' b'5']]
Result for output key class_ids:
[[2]]
Result for output key classes:
[[b'2']]
Result for output key logits:
[[ 0.11128154 -0.44881764  0.31520572 -0.08318427 -0.3479367  -0.08883157]]
Result for output key probabilities:
[[0.19719791 0.11263006 0.2418051  0.16234797 0.12458517 0.16143374]]
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you please share the `SignatureDef` of your Model. Also, please share the `saved_model_cli` command which you could execute successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it happens because you are using TF2 docker image, try

```
tensorflow/serving:1.15.0-rc2
```

docker image, I hope it fixes this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Try also calling tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior() when app that is saving your model is started.